# one time used function - should I use malloc or not

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

I have a little bit long C code and there is one function that would be called only once. That includes some variables like `char array`, `int`. The code is something like this:

```
void onetimefcn(){
    char example_array1[20]="hello...";
    //...
    char example_array10[14]="hej...";
    int x=3,y=432,z=321,d=4439;
    //some arithmatic operation
    //some char array operation: strcpy, strcmp
    // some for loops and if else conditions
}
```

I will run that code on an embedded linux device. I wonder if I should use `malloc` for the all variables on that function then `free` them? would it help to use the resources efficiently or could it arise some serious problems (if it is the case, what might happen)?

Comment: Do they cause problems? Perhaps some kind of premature optimisation is going on?

Comment: What is the available device memory size? a few kB or less ?

Comment: the device has 250MHz CPU and 64MB DDR-RAM

Comment: But their scope is not out of that function am I right? When function ends, do they get deleted?

Comment: that function will be deleted by itself. But, I also have some variables that will be used once on the main(). would it make sense to use malloc for the variables that will be used once inside the main()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `malloc` would be *less* efficient than implicit stack allocation. The stack is an extremely efficient allocation mechanism, as both allocation and deallocation boils down to a simple update of the stack pointer, leaving behind no fragmentation.